# 1 / 0 Sparse Matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I have a data of 1000 rows and 2 cols. I want to convert it to a matrix of one's and zero's such that the 1st column is Column A, 1st row is Column B and whenever a certain value of A matches B, it returns 1 or 0. I did this for a column but while trying to copy, the formula breaks.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Is there any other easy way to do this in Excel or any other language like Python or R.

***Excel Screenshot:***
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Your formula is almost correct, but the first reference should be `C$1`. To populate the rest of the matrix, select the full range starting with C2 and enter the formula with Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

`=(COUNTIF($C$1:INDEX($1:$1,MAX(($1:$1<>"")*(COLUMN($1:$1)))),$B2)>0)*1`

Counts if the text in B2 occurs in the indexed first row starting from column 3 to the last non empty column. If only one match is possible, you can narrow it down to

`=COUNTIF($C$1:INDEX($1:$1,MAX(($1:$1<>"")*(COLUMN($1:$1)))),$B2)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not working though, for some reason, it's returning every value as 1.

Comment: If you drag it down `$B2` would change into `$B3` etc. Maybe the formula needs entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` (so it will become an array formula). When done correctly the formula will be wrapped in `{` `}`.